# Howto obtain Per-Interface statistics on windows

Tags: winapi

I am trying to find the most used Network card on windows 200 or XP.  I planned to obtain the number of packets sent trough each NIC to determine the main NIC.

I thought IP Helper might give me this information but also it looks like the functions in IP helper only give stats for all interfaces.  I know this can be done. Any ideas?

Many Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx) ? [Here's an example](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/wmi/samples/hw/#Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration.htm) of interrogating the set of network adaptors. Note that it includes stats such as the number of forwarded packets for *each* adaptor.

Answer (score 0):

You could use from any number of available packet sniffer programs out there: [Top Packet Sniffers](http://sectools.org/sniffers.html)

Also look here: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer)

Comment: Need to determine the busiest interface as soon as my app starts. A packets sniffer would take time.