# Measure the current network traffic in Windows

Tags: c++, winapi

I have been looking for a solution all evening now and i cannot find anything. My problem is that I am writing a program which collects statistics from windows servers. The only thing i cannot find is how to get the current network usage on the system. Like the usage you can see in the Task manager. I found some functions on MSDN but some of them are only available on windows systems which have at least windows vista and some functions, or better the structures for those functions have problems with 10GBit network interfaces. Anyone knows any solid solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278812/howto-obtain-per-interface-statistics-on-windows) may help?